# How are Liferay Remote Services accessed from an application that's not a portlet?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

When a user logs into the Liferay Portal I want to show a visualization of the list of files that they have access to. This visualization would be done using Javascript, but preferably not inside a portlet, but just being run on the Portal homepage.

I was looking into some of the [JSON web service examples](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/json-web-services-invocation-examples), but I was a bit confused on **how to invoke some of the Liferay remote services to access the document files from an application that doesn't extend the Liferay portlet class**.

**Is this possible to do this from outside a portlet or would I need to implement something using URL parameters as referred in one of the Liferay examples?** I don't know there is something I'm not understanding here.

*EDIT: I want to implement these remote service requests for the visualization inside of a custom theme that I am using. Yet, due to Olaf's recommendation, I will look to see if implementing my visualization and service requests inside of a portlet would be a better solution to my needs.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. I'm not sure what you mean with "not inside a portlet, but just being run on the portal homepage" - typically everything that's displayed on the UI is encapsulated within a portlet (well, or within the theme - but for maintainability reasons I'd keep it out of the theme)

You'll need the `p_auth` token - how to obtain it is part of the documentation that you link (or the surrounding chapters)

If you run into specific problems, please edit your question and list them (and your code). Currently your question reads "Is this possible...?" and the answer to this is "Yes".

Comment: Looking over the documentation another time after posting this question, a solution I was thinking of was implementing a visualization of the documents that the currently signed-in user has permissions to view, to be shown on the portal homepage through adding it on to my custom theme, but you mentioned that you'd recommend keeping it out of there for maintainability reasons. Could you elaborate on that? I'll edit my answer to elaborate what I stated here.

Comment: I'd still implement this in a portlet and embed the portlet in the theme

Comment: Thank you, Olaf. The custom theme we are using seemed to be a good place to implement the logic for our visualization and would allow us to implement the service requests as well, but I will see if moving it into a portlet instead would be better for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Go for it. FYI: Implementing in a portlet is a strong preference of mine: It's just properly separated from the visual stuff and in a place where I'd rather expect some active content to live. *Technically* it will work in the theme. I just feel that it's the wrong place to solve the problem. And it's easy to embed a portlet in the theme, so both go along quite well.